# Make a program come to foreground but not clickable

Tags: windows, programming-languages, clickable, foreground

I'm pretty new to programming and I wanted to create a new project.
I have something in mind, but before I start learning how to program it, I need to know something.

I want the program to be able to stay on the foreground, so it always visible when active, but I want it to be only clickable when a certain key-combo (or something like it) is entered.

So it stays visible, but not clickable unless a specific key is tapped, when you go back to the other program (for example while watching a movie) it becomes unclickable again.

Is this possible? And if so, what language you advise me to start this project in?

EDIT: let's say only Windows for now, can I use java for this? How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Are we talking about Windows-only or Multi-Platform or any other?

Comment: There are ways to do such things in any language, but they are not very portable (i.e. this depends a lot on the OS and Window Manager). Java hides many of the portability issues from you, as do frameworks like Qt in C++.

Comment: @Fildor let's take Windows-only

Comment: Yes, you can use Java. I guess a starting point for your research could be [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My C++/Win32 API approach:

The "not clickable" part: just throw away any messages your application receives prior to whatever key combination you're looking for has been pressed.  The trickier part is if you want a message aimed at your window to pass through and go to the window behind yours - you would first obtain the [`HWND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the window behind, and then use the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to forward all unwanted messages to that window.

The "stays at the top" part is even easier.  Use the extended window style [`WS_EX_TOPMOST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your call to [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930455.aspx) and it'll stay at the top no matter what.

[Here's a good Win32 API tutorial](http://www.winprog.org) if I made your brain explode.